# Solving a system of linear equations

Tags: equation-solving

It might be the easiest question. However, I need a little help.
I try to solve the equations coded below in order to find unknowns `L`, `M` and `NN`. However, `Solve` gives me 0 for each. Could you give an idea or do you have a solution for this?

```
Solve[
  -10.49*L + 12*M - 15*NN == 0 && 
  12*L - 30.49*M + 10*NN == 0 && 
  -15*L + 10*M - 24.49*NN == 0, 
  {L, M, NN}]
```

Comment: This is normal since all right members are 0. Put 1 in one equation and you will see a change

Comment: ...and don't use upper-case letters to start the names of variables as this can conflict with naming policy for internal *Mathematica* variables.

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki The trivial solution is always a solution of a homogeneous system of linear equations, but some of them have also a non-trivial solution - it depends on the determinant of the matrix of coefficients. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

```
eqs = {-10.49*L + 12*M - 15*NN == 0, 
        12*L - 30.49*M + 10*NN == 0,
       -15*L + 10*M - 24.49*NN == 0};

Solve[eqs, {L, M, NN}]
```

> {{L -> 0., M -> 0., NN -> 0.}}

Extract the matrix of coefficients:

```
c = CoefficientArrays[eqs, Variables @ eqs];

MatrixForm @ c[[2]]
```

[image]

Its determinant

```
Det @ c[[2]]
```

> 2.92595

is non-zero, so the only solution to this - homogeneous - system of linear equations is indeed a trivial one.

Comment: `UpperTriangularize@First@LUDecomposition@c[[2]] // MatrixForm`